# RadCaptcha error message not included in Validation Summary

Tags: asp.net, validation, telerik, captcha

I have this code in my page that that has required field validation in the textboxes. The other controls are working fine(I have not included the other controls because its confusing) except for this radcaptcha. I have included it in the validation group but it is still not being displayed in the validation summary when it pops up. Thanks in advance.

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td> 
              <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                    Width="100%" Style="border-color: Black" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Red"
                    ValidationGroup="Group"></asp:ValidationSummary>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
              <div class="divContainer">
                   <telerik:RadCaptcha ID="RadCaptcha1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group" EnableRefreshImage="True" Display="Static" CssClass="CaptchaCss" Height="155px" Width="254px" CaptchaAudioLinkButtonText=""  CaptchaLinkButtonText="" CaptchaImage-ImageCssClass="CaptchaImageCss" CaptchaImage-Width="231" CaptchaImage-Height="70" CaptchaTextBoxCssClass="rcTextBoxClass" CaptchaImage-EnableCaptchaAudio="True" CaptchaTextBoxLabelCssClass="rcLabelClass" ForeColor="#FFDC72" ErrorMessage="Invalid input"></telerik:RadCaptcha>

              </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that RadCaptcha performs the validation on the server, while the standard ASP.NET validation controls have client-side validation, which kicks in first, enabled by default. The client-side validation of all control in the validation group has to be disabled so that the error message of the captcha appears with the rest. You can check this in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/captcha/examples/validationsummary/defaultcs.aspx

You should use **validationGroup** property.